# How to bring UserControl from MainForm to front by clicking ListView Item in another UserControl on the MainForm

Tags: c#

I have the following problem:

I have created a MainForm with several UserControls on it. I have a ListView on the UserControl2.
I want to click an item in this ListView and with this click the UserControl1 should be displayed.

What I have tried is the following:

In UserControl2 the item is choosen by the MousClick event

```
public void MyListView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

In this event the code part will be executed:

```
MainForms.MainForm fMain = new MainForms.MainForm();

foreach(Control c in fMain.Controls)
{
    if (c.Name == "UserControl1")
    {
        UserControlls MyControl = new UserControlls();
        MyControl.RefreshControl(ID, Text);
        c.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

The code part is working without any errors, but the the UserControl1 is not shown.

Has anybody an idea what is wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT 15.03.2021:

I found a solution by not initializing a new MainForm, but use the active form.

So I changed follwoing code:

```
MainForms.MainForm fMain = new MainForms.MainForm();
```

to:

```
var fMain = MainForms.MainForm.ActiveForm.Controls;
```

and than loop throu fMain.

```
foreach (Control c in fMain)
{
  if (c.Name == "UserControl1")
  {
    UserControlls MyControl = new UserControlls();
    MyControl.RefreshControl(Id, Text);
    c.Refresh();
    c.BringToFront();
   }
}
```

So my UserControl1 is shown afterwards, but without the necessarry infos.

Comment: `new MainForms.MainForm` cannot work, you must use a reference to the existing object, the one you're looking at.  If it is what you actually meant to do then add `fMain.Show();`

Comment: Ok, and how can I set and use the reference you mean?